fastest way to get 0..=63 into zmm register?
is there a better alternative to _mm512_set_epi8(63, 62, ..., 1, 0)? E.g. would it be better to produce the high half by adding broadcasted 32 to the low half, or some other tricks? How do additional instructions weigh vs loading more constant data from memory?
